# How can I lower voltage coming in to a kiln?

Tags: voltage, resistors

I have a small firing kiln. It heats up to quickly for my ceramic pieces. I was wondering if I could reduce the voltage coming into it so it could heat up slower ? And if I could how could I go about doing it? I was thinking I could use a resistor, but I don't know how to apply it or if I could where would the resister to go ?

Comment: A typical way of adjusting a large heater is to do on/off control or PWM control.

Comment: It runs on 12 amps. What would be a proper controller I could use?

Comment: My favorite controllers are made by [Omega Engineering](http://www.omega.com/guides/tempcontrol.html).  Fuji and Watlow make them too.  So do many others.  There is a half-dozen standardized form factors.  On a different note, you'll need an external relay for 12 amperes.

Answer (score 1):

A crude way to reduce the power would be to put a rectifier in series with the power. It would reduce the RMS voltage to 71%. For example, a 30A 600V such as the
[STTH30R06W](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00045268.pdf) would be suitable and is very inexpensive. You would need to keep it away from the heat of the kiln and to add a suitable electrically insulated heat sink.

If you want to do closed-loop control you would need a sensor capable of kiln temperatures (a heavy gauge CA/K type or a platinum-rhodium type such as R/S), and a controller with ramped setpoint capability, and a contactor capable of handling the heater current. You may also need to add a redundant over temperature cutoff for safety reasons, if one is not already present.

Comment: I think a diode would reduce the power (and hence the RMS) by 50%?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen   If the resistance stays fixed then \$\sqrt{2} \$ voltage is 50% power- but you know that.

Comment: Make that \$ 1\over \sqrt{2}\$ voltage, lol.

Comment: Monday morning here :( - but I think 'reduces the power to 50%' would have been a more useful way of describing the effect - and it would have prevented me from making a fool of myself :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to treat your oven as a big light bulb, and buy a high-power dimmer. You can get a 15 amp unit for about $60. It will allow you to gradually crank up the oven temperature.

This isn't a shopping site, but Google on high power dimmer, and you should be able to find what you need.

An even easier (and cheaper) way has a drawback: you can only change the power in two steps. Buy a standard electric room heater which will put out 1500 watts. Connect this in series with your kiln. When you start up the kiln, the heater will be limited to about half power. After an appropriate delay, remove the heater and plug the kiln directly into your AC. The kiln will now be at full power, and can get to full temperature. This will not be as gradual as using a dimmer, but it will be cheap and simple, as long as you can work with the temperature profile it produces.